# Time it will take to complete the project if two people work together (word problem)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If Iris spends 3 days and Olivia spends 5 days on a project, 1/2 of the work can be done. If instead Iris spends 5 days and Olivia spend 3 days, then 1/3 of the work is done. How long does it take to complete the project if Iris and Olivia work together?

I attempted but I don't know if what I did so far is correct and what to do next.

$$6I+10O=W$$
$$15I+9O=W$$
$$6I=W-20O$$
$$2.5W-16O=W$$
$$1.5W=16O$$
$$\left(10 \frac{2}{3}\right)O=W$$

Comment: The first two equation are correct. The rest is a little bit confusing. You can set W=1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: If they both spend 8 days on the project, they've gotten 5/6 of the work done.

Comment: Rather nice of the problem-poser to set up the situation that way...

Comment: Too bad it's kind of a bodge.  It does point the way to one of the more important ways to handle simultaneous equations: just add the corresponding sides together.

Comment: Hey, take advantage of any helpful features of a problem (like convenient numerical values) whenever they present themselves!  I was just noting that these rate problems aren't often set up in such a handy way...

Answer (score 2):

You have correctly found the rate of Olivia's work as $ \ O \ = \ \frac{3}{32} \ W \ $ , that is, she could complete the entire job alone in $ \ \frac{32}{3} \ $ days.  You can then solve for Iris' rate, $ \ I \ $ , using either of the equations in your simultaneous system.  The time required for both of them to complete the task together is $ \ \frac{W}{I \ + \ O} \ $ ; the " $  W  $ " will cancel out, leaving a numerical value in days.  (Not an integer in this problem, but not too ugly a rational number...)

[I should mention, incidentally, that a grader would probably deduct points, even though your value for $ \ O \ $ is correct.  Your third line appears to have a typo and what follows does not appear to be algebraically correct or is mistyped (or possibly mis-edited?).]

Comment: You know I didn't even bother calculating Iris's work rate.  She is a *lazy bum*.

Comment: I don't know about lazy, but slow... _real slow_ ...

Answer (score 1):

It hard to understand, what have you written.

Here is the traditional way. The way of Dan Uznanski is more clever.

I would first define the following variables:

$V_I$=The proportion of the project is done by Iris in one day.

$V_O$=The proportion of the project is done by Olivia in one day.

It follows the equations:

$3V_I+5V_O=\frac{1}{2}$

$5V_I+3V_O=\frac{1}{3}$

This equation ystem can be solved.

The work is done, if $(V_I+V_O)\cdot T=1$

T: Time to finish the project, if Iris and Olivia work together.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_1$ be the work done by Iris in one day
Let $x_2$ be the work done by Olivia in one day
Let $W$ be the total work to be done to complete the project

$$3x_1+5x_2=\frac{1}{2}W$$

$$5x_1+3x_2=\frac{1}{3}W$$

Solving above simultaneously will give you $x_1$ and $x_2$ in terms of $W$.

(Number of days reqd to complete the project)$\times(x_1+x_2)=W$